# Parse data to CSV file

Tags: linux, excel, bash, parsing, csv

I am working on a bash script where I am trying to first remove the three last lines and then parse it to a excel-format file to being able to make a graph.

This is the command I run:

```
  ./a.out | tail -7
```

Output

```
Copy:            3374.3     0.047656     0.047417     0.047898
Scale:           3337.4     0.048221     0.047942     0.048456
Add:             3616.4     0.066834     0.066364     0.067662
Triad:           3597.4     0.067162     0.066715     0.067727
-------------------------------------------------------------
Solution Validates: avg error less than 1.000000e-13 on all three arrays
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

Questions I have:

1. How can I remove the three last lines ?
2. How can I parse the data into a excel file to make graphs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > How can I remove the three last lines ?

```
head -n-3 myfile.txt
```

> > How can I parse the data into a excel file to make graphs?

```
awk '{printf("%s,%s,%s,%s,%s", $1, $2, $3, $4)}' myfile.txt
```

So if you combine both of them, your command would be:

```
head -n-3 myfile.txt | awk '{printf("%s,%s,%s,%s,%s", $1, $2, $3, $4)}'
```

Comment: Thanks! The -n-3 worked, but the combined command does not write anything to the file.